# Is there any extension / plugin to webpack to create inline CSS from SASS code?

Tags: html, css, webpack, sass

I need to create a specific `HTML` code with only `inline CSS`.

I have this HTML file:

```
<div id="highlighted">This is the highlighted text.</div>
```

And I have this `Sass` file:

```
#highlighted {
    background: #ff0;
}
```

Now I need to this output HTML code with inline CSS:

```
<div id="highlighted" style="background: #ff0;">This is the highlighted text.</div>
```

Is there any extension, plugin, tool, anything to webpack to solve this problem?

Comment: flagging off-topic: Recommendations are off-topic here...

Comment: webpack is a widely used tool to development, and this is a specific, concrete development problem

Comment: be that as it may, your question still asks for a tool/plugin/extension ...

Comment: okay, but I don't know any other forum where I can ask help in this question

Comment: generic SASS forums?

Comment: this is a webpack question, not a sass question

Comment: then generic webpack forum..

Comment: There's this other Stack Exchange forum called [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but if you prefer to post it here just rephrase the question as: this is my code, this is my Webpack config (with something you have tried), this is what I get, but this is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`html-webpack-inline-style-plugin`](https://github.com/djaax/html-webpack-inline-style-plugin) does that using [`juice`](https://github.com/Automattic/juice), so this:

```
<style>#highlighted{ background: #ff0; }</style>
<div id="highlighted">This is the highlighted text.</div>
```

Will produce this:

```
<div id="highlighted" style="background: #ff0;">This is the highlighted text.</div>
```

You can play around with `juice` and its different options online here: https://automattic.github.io/juice/.